# I'm using the same API and I want to use it to perform CRUD operations to multiple mongo DBs in the same cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A new database is created each time a user doc is added to a collection in the main DB. I want to create a new DB connection to a user DB specific to a user that gets authenticated from the main DB and be able to use this connection across the API.

I'm using schema export method for the main DB and use the models like:

```
const usersModel = await mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
const user_contact = await usersModel.findOne({ user_contact: scontact });
```

I create the models for userDB after I create the user in the main DB as below:

```
userDB.model('Staff', staffSchema)
userDB.model('Class', classSchema)
```

I want to create a connection to the userDB when a user logs in at the main DB, and user that connection in other models dynamically, something like importing it and using it another file maybe to create a new staff.